# Installation gradle in Github Actions

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, selenide

I used gradle.yml before, around six month ago. But now in my new project it's not working (tests are failed).
Maybe is it related to changes about authorization by token or access with Selenide? Locally tests are passed.

My gradle.yml

```
    name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 15
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '15'
        distribution: 'adopt'

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build --info
```

*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.*

*Error: Process completed with exit code 1.*

[some logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeMEa.png)

Comment: Could you please provide us with the error message? Without it it’s hard to know what is going wrong.

Comment: @MarijnKneppers sure, sorry.